# Getting Fousquare check-in data from public profiles

Tags: foursquare

I'm looking to get check-in data that includes user ID, place and time information, from Foursquare users that have public accounts. What is the best way to do this that doesn't require each user's authentication? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's just not possible using the API. In order to access checkin information a user *must* authenticate with your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need specific users, you can search Twitter for Foursquare checkins published there and then scrape the linked checkin pages for the user ID, place and time information.